# Displaying $_FILES data (simlar to $_POST)

Tags: plugin-development, uploads, filesystem

I'm trying to display $_FILES in wp-admin, and I've been using add_filter and apply_filter, but it does not seem to show the $_FILES array values. My goal is to show the values in $_FILES so I can upload it to a specified directory (But this is going to be in the future).

**Upload Screen Meta Box**

```
function upload_screen() { 
  print_r(apply_filters('demo_fileupload',$_FILES));
  echo "<br>";
  echo 'Upload Files<input type="file" name="" /><br>';
}
```

The next function should return the file array (this is where the problem lies). So I tried using `add_filter`, but does not seem to work.

**File Upload Function** but return `$file array` for now.

```
function demo_fileupload($file) {
  return $file;
}
```

**Add Filter**

```
add_filter('save_post','demo_fileupload',10,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to show `$_FILES` or `$_POST`, you will need to create a sumbenu_page under the post_type. Then, you will be able to manipulate `$_FILES` and `$_POST` in whichever way you want.

This means that `upload_screen()` function should be a submenu page.